# how to join top 1 quickly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with devices, and a second table with performance counters.  So I have device A  which has lets say 1000 entries in the performance counters table.  I am trying to get all the devices, 2500 of them, and their most recent performance counter.  I have used an Outer Apply,  which does accomplish the desired results, but the query takes 5 minutes to execute.

Is this the best way to get the info I am looking for or is there a better way?  Is the performance of this query normal, and I am just asking too much?  I am thinking of creating a third 'temp' table nightly that will hold this data so I can display and query the info quickly.  What are the best practices for something like this?

Here is my current query:

```
   select * from Device D
      OUTER APPLY
          ( select top 1 *
              FROM PerformanceCounterValues
              where instance_id = D.pkid
              order by collection_time desc
           ) as tbl2
```

----- Solved ----

Here is my final actual query, and it works in 0 seconds.

```
SELECT pkid, D.IDDevice, D.IDHardware, H.IDRecorder, D.Name, D.Description, H.Name as HardwareName, H.URI, R.HostName, R.Name as RecorderInstance, tbl2.collection_time, tbl2.raw_value, tbl2.calculated_value
  FROM [Surveillance].[dbo].[PerformanceCounterInstance] PCI
  JOIN [Surveillance].[dbo].[Devices] D on D.IDDevice = (SELECT REPLACE(STUFF([instance_name],1,CHARINDEX('[',[instance_name]),''),']',''))
  JOIN [Surveillance].[dbo].[Hardware] H on H.IDHardware = D.IDHardware
  JOIN [Surveillance].[dbo].[Recorders] R on R.IDRecorder = H.IDRecorder
    OUTER APPLY
    ( select top 1 *
        FROM [Surveillance].[dbo].[PerformanceCounterValue]
        where instance_id = PCI.pkid
        order by collection_time desc
        ) as tbl2
  where category_name = 'VideoOS Recording Server Device Storage'
  and D.Enabled = 1
```

It was just setting up the index that made the speed increase.

Comment: You may want to revise your index strategy. You should ask this on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Im not sure of the policies, can I cross post this there, or should I take this down and repost on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is an OK post.  In my opinion.

Comment: A couple of questions... What do the indexes look like for these two tables? How many rows are in the Device table? Can you post the execution plan for this query?

Comment: @David: If you want the question to be moved to dba.se, flag it, leaving a message to moderators

Comment: Justin, you led me to figure out the issue.  I didnt know what an execution plan was.  I googled, figured it out, and figured out I had a missing index on a field.  This is not a db I created, and the table originally had a clustered Index setup, but that was causing the high cost.  Thanks, and I learned something new.

Comment: Justin, if you want credit for an answer throw something together and I will mark as correct, since you did lead me in the right direction.  Thanks a ton

Comment: @DavidStetler, though my question may have pointed you in the right direction, you were the one who ultimately figured out that it needed an index and which index to create. No need for me to take credit.

Comment: @DavidStetler - it is okay to answer yourself and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @DavidStetler It is however *not* OK to post your answer *inside* your question. You need to post an answer below and remove the solution from your question. You can then mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: David - it would be nice if you could post your solution as an answer then accept it instead of it residing in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabled Index and used this query:

```
SELECT pkid, D.IDDevice, D.IDHardware, H.IDRecorder, D.Name, D.Description, H.Name as HardwareName, H.URI, R.HostName, R.Name as RecorderInstance, tbl2.collection_time, tbl2.raw_value, tbl2.calculated_value
  FROM [Surveillance].[dbo].[PerformanceCounterInstance] PCI
  JOIN [Surveillance].[dbo].[Devices] D on D.IDDevice = (SELECT REPLACE(STUFF([instance_name],1,CHARINDEX('[',[instance_name]),''),']',''))
  JOIN [Surveillance].[dbo].[Hardware] H on H.IDHardware = D.IDHardware
  JOIN [Surveillance].[dbo].[Recorders] R on R.IDRecorder = H.IDRecorder
    OUTER APPLY
    ( select top 1 *
        FROM [Surveillance].[dbo].[PerformanceCounterValue]
        where instance_id = PCI.pkid
        order by collection_time desc
        ) as tbl2
  where category_name = 'VideoOS Recording Server Device Storage'
  and D.Enabled = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  select D.pkid, max(PerformanceCounterValues.collection_time)
  from Device D
  join PerformanceCounterValues
  on  PerformanceCounterValues.instance_id = D.pkid 
  group by D.pkid
```

Comment: I have other info besides just the pkid and the max performanceCounter that need to be included so I dont think the group by clause will work for me.

Comment: If this yields better performance can expand on it to get addition information. Does this yield better performance?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whaty indexing would be best for the `outer apply` query, but you can try adding an index on `(instance_id, collection_time)` for this one:

```
   SELECT 
        d.*                --- whatever columns you need from Device 
      , p.*                --- and from PerformanceCounterValues
   FROM Device AS d
     JOIN
       ( SELECT instance_id, 
                MAX(collection_time) AS max_collection_time
         FROM PerformanceCounterValues
         GROUP BY instance_id
       ) AS grp
       ON  grp.instance_id = d.pkid
     JOIN PerformanceCounterValues AS p
       ON  p.instance_id = grp.instance_id 
       AND p.collection_time = grp.max_collection_time ;
```

It would also help if you added the execution plan of your query in your  question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to select top one directly on the join, i have about 20,000 corresponding entries in one talbe for which i want to fetch the first entry time from a Logs table. my query executes in less than 2 sec(MsSql 2008)

```
select D.pkid, pvc.*
from Device D
join PerformanceCounterValues as pcv on pcv.PrimaryKey = (SELECT top(1) PrimaryKey From      PerformanceCounterValues WHERE instance_id = D.pkid ORDER BY collection_time )
```

Comment: trying now, had high hopes, but I dont think it is improving the performance at all.  Crossing over 5 minute mark and nothing returned so far.  On your query how many rows are you returning in 2 seconds?  I have no problem searching for 1 device and getting the corresponding counters to return in under a second, I only have a "problem" when I am returning 2500 rows.

Comment: i was returning almost 20,000 rows. How many rows u have in PerformanceCounterValues table??

Comment: For that, i think u can try Left Outter. U need all devices to be listed but only Top PerformanceVounterValue right??